# How to get plain link with views-data-export module in CSV?

Tags: views, navigation, importing-exporting

I have a view with field that provides a simple link to the content.

**Problem**: When I export the data into a csv file there is only the word `link` instead of a link.

How can I get there the content URL instead of the word `link`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is not an interactive format. When you export column with literal "link" in it's data, you get link in CSV.

Instead of exporting word column, with link added at rewrite or template level, export column that actually contains the URL you want. For nodes, [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/548292) indicates that you should be able to use 'Path' field, description: 'The aliased path to this node.'.

Comment: Well, that is the problem. There is only this single field (`content: link`) which `Provide a simple link to the content.`.

Comment: @Jurik see https://www.drupal.org/node/548292

Comment: That `Path` thing made the difference! Additionally you can setup the link to absolute link at `rewrite results`.